# Laravel Resource Router ignoring eager loaded data and getting a new query

Tags: laravel-4

In my resource router, I have this function, which is supposed to eager load only the rows that have the configureName of $id. The problem is that when I call $demo->demoSettings resource router is ignoring my eager load and grabbing all of the demoSettings related to this $demo.

This isn't the only instance of this problem that I have. I also have a couple loops where I am injecting data into my api index from related tables for convenience purposes. The moment I add a call to access my eager loaded data, it queries again and injects the data into my resource return. I've worked around it by using unset in the other instances, but this one is different because I actually want the list of data, rather than a single value.

```
public function show($demoId,$id)
{
    $demo = Demo::with(array('DemoSettings' => function($query) use ($id)
    {
        $query->where('configureName', '=', $id);
    }))->where('demoId','=',$demoId)->first();
    return $demo->demoSettings;
}
```

Demo Model

```
class Demo extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'Demo';
public $timestamps = false;

/**
 * The key column used by the model.
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'idDemos';

/**
 * one(demo) to many(demoSettings) relationship
 * @return array of the demoSettings associated with the demo
 */
public function demoSettings()
{
    return $this->hasMany('DemoSettings','idDemos','idDemos')->orderBy('configureName','asc');
}
}
```

DemoSettings Model

```
class DemoSettings extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'DemoSettings';
    /**
     * The key column used by the model.
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'idDemoSettings';

    /**
     * many(demoSettings) to one(demo) relationship
     * @return demo the parent record
     */
    public function demo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Demo','idDemos','idDemos');
    }

}
```

Route

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function(){
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'demos'), function(){
    Route::resource('/', 'api_DemosController', array('only' => array('index','store','destroy','show')));
    Route::resource('/{demoId}/settings', 'api_DemoSettingsController', array('only' => array('index','store','show')));
});
```

});

Comment: Show the model and route definition. Also what's `$demoId` variable?

Comment: I've added the requested code into the original request. $demoId is a variable from the route, as you can see now in the route definition.